# How do i get a RAM Dump from an LG G3 Smartphone?

Tags: android, dump, malware, lg, volatility

i have to check an LG G3 for malware with Volatility. 
So i need a ram dump. 
Has anyone an idea how to get this?

Thanks for your answers.

Regards, Felix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some instruction to do this :

https://www.sensepost.com/blog/2013/poking-around-in-android-memory/

And

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62300/memory-dumping-android

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GameGuardian](http://gameguardian.net/download) for this. Need root.

Memory editor tab - menu - memory dump - select range and folder - press ok - wait for toast "Dump end".

Here some video examples how to do this:

- [How to dump memory of any running processes in Android -
  GameGuardian](https://gameguardian.net/forum/gallery/image/248-how-to-dump-memory-of-any-running-processes-in-android-gameguardian/)
- [How to dump odex file from memory on Android -
  GameGuardian](https://gameguardian.net/forum/gallery/image/251-how-to-dump-odex-file-from-memory-on-android-gameguardian/)
- [How to dump deleted file from memory on Android -
  GameGuardian](https://gameguardian.net/forum/gallery/image/252-how-to-dump-deleted-file-from-memory-on-android-gameguardian/)